# Trying to pass images from a model/helper file to a slideshow in CodeIgniter using a an array and foreach

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, foreach

I have a controller pages.php:

```
 class Pages extends CI_Controller {
     public function index($page = 'home')
     {

      if ( ! file_exists('application/views/pages/'.$page.'.php'))
      {
           // Whoops, we don't have a page for that!
           show_404();
      }
      $this->lang->load('common/menu.php');
      $this->lang->load('pages/'.$page.'.php');
      $data = array();
      $this->load->helper('slideshow');
      $data['slideshow'] = get_image_array(); 

      $this->load->view('templates/common/header', $data);
      $this->load->view('modules/slideshow', $data);
      $this->load->view('pages/'.$page, $data);
      $this->load->view('templates/common/footer', $data);
     }
}
```

My slideshow_helper file:

```
function get_image_array(){
    $images = array(img("slideshow/desktop/home1.jpg", "one"),img("slideshow/desktop/home2.jpg", "two"),img("slideshow/desktop/home3.jpg", "three"));
    $captions = array("first image", "second image", "third image");
    return array_combine($images, $captions);
}
```

And the slideshow view:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <div id="carousel-desktop" class="carousel slide  visible-md visible-lg">
                <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                    <li data-target="#carousel-desktop" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                    <li data-target="#carousel-desktop" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                    <li data-target="#carousel-desktop" data-slide-to="2"></li>
                </ol>
                <div class="carousel-inner">
                    <?php $i = 1; ?>
                    <?php foreach ($image as $imageSrc => $caption ):?>
                    <?php $item_class = ($i == 1) ? 'item active' : 'item'; ?>
                    <div class="<?php echo $item_class; ?>">
                        <?php  echo $image; if($caption != ""){ ?>
                            <div class="carousel-caption">
                                <?php  echo $caption;?>
                            </div>
                        <?php } ?>
                    </div>
                    <?php $i++; ?>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                 </div>
                 <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-desktop" data-slide="prev">
                     <span class="icon-chevron-sign-left"></span>
                 </a>
                 <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-desktop" data-slide="next">
                     <span class="icon-chevron-sign-right"></span>
                 </a>
            </div>
            <br />
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
<br />
</div>
```

Unfortunately this does not work am I missing something? I get the following error:

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined variable: image

Filename: pages/home.php
```

-AND-

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Filename: pages/home.php
```

Or is it completely wrong? I should point out that this site will **not** have access to a database.

When I have the array in the view file it works.

What I am trying to do is have a different model/helper file for each page as each page of this controller will have a slideshow but each with different images. So rather than recreating the view part countless times I want to simply have a new array for each page. I was thinking of using something like:

```
$this->load->helper('pages/'.$page); 
-or-
$this->load->model('pages/'.$page.'.php');
```

so that each page has its own model/helper filer but obviously as I cannot get the first bit working I have no idea if this second bit will work.

Any help will be very much appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You store images in `$data['slideshow'];` index, right? So simply use `$slideshow` in your view:

```
<?php foreach ($slideshow as $imageSrc => $caption ): ?>
```

Comment: changed $data['slideshow']; to $data['image']; now works thanks saved a lot of head scratching :)